# cargar direccion de foto en BD

Tags: php, mysql, imagen, checkbox, datatable

Buen dia

Me podrian ayudar tengo el siguiente codigo para almacenar la direccion de una imagen a mi base de datos y de esta manera al consultar solo la busco en mi carpeta imagenes que tengo en mi proyecto pero por alguna razon solo en ciertos registros me arroja el mensaje de actualizacion exitosa y en otros solo se queda la pagina en blanco sin arrojarme algun error o mensaje de exitoso y cuando reviso el registro no tiene la direccion de la imagen guardada si me pudiera ayudar a saber que hice mal para que esto sucediera se los agradeceria.

Cabe mencionar que mediante un check box yo selecciono que registros quiero que se suba su foto, pero si solo selecciono uno al azar en algunos si la almacena y en otros se queda la pagina en blanco
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de tabla en donde actualizo y cargo la imagen

```
 <div class="card-body">
                                <form data-toggle="validator"  action="./../conexion/ingemp2.php" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <table id="employee_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                                <th>Numero Reloj</th>
                                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                                <th>Puesto</th>
                                                <th>Categoria</th>
                                                <th>Departamento</th>
                                                <th>Turno</th>
                                                <th>Subir</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        
                                        <tbody>
                                            
                                        <?php
                                            
                                            $fecha_actual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
                                            
                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                                
                                                $id=$row['id_emp'];
                                                
                                            ?>
                                                    
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id_emp']; ?>" /></td>
                                                        <td align=center><?= $row['codigo_persona'] ?></td>
                                                        <td align=center><?= $row['Nombre'] ?></td>
                                                        <td align=center><?= $row['Puesto'] ?></td>
                                                        <td align=center><?= $row['Categoria'] ?></td>
                                                        <td align=center><?= $row['Departamento'] ?></td>
                                                        <td align=center><?= $row['Turno'] ?></td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        <input type="file" id="seleccionArchivos" name="image">
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                
                                            ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

y este el codigo donde recibo mis datos mediante un POST y realizo la actualizacion del registro

```
<?php

// Include the database configuration file
include 'conexion.php';
$statusMsg = '';

$id = $_POST['id'];
//var_dump($id);
$count = count($id);

// File upload path
$targetDir = "./../img/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){

    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
    
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){

            for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                //Actualizamos Base de datos.
                mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE empleados SET Imagen='$fileName' WHERE id_emp='$id[$i]'");
                ?>
                <script>
                alert("Actualizacion Exitosa");
                window.location.href='./../work/EmpReg2.php';
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
?>
```

De antemano gracias

Comment: ¿Has verificado en la base de datos qué ocurre con alguno de esos registros que falla, por ejemplo, si es que la columna concerniente está en blanco en dichos registros, si no tiene relación con otra tabla, si esa imagen existe realmente, etc?

Comment: Si ya lo he revisado y de echo la columna el campo siempre estara en blanco por que se cargara la imagen despues del registro de datos ya que este se realiza mediante una importacion de archivo excel y como te comento si de mi tabla selecicono cualquier registro al azar y le doy cargar foto en algunos si la carga y en otros solo se queda la pagina en blanco sin mostrar nada y sin cargar la imagen

Comment: La imagen yo la selecciono desde mi equipo y al realizar el update la imagen debe guardarse en mi carpeta img dentro del proyecto y en la base de datos solo almacena el nombre de la imagen pero como solo se queda la pagina en blanco no guarda la imagen en la carpeta del proyecto ni el registro en la base de datos

Comment: Depura tu código, haciendo pruebas in situ allí donde falla y si no encuentras la forma de resolverlo entonces dinos, en la pregunta, *he probado tal cosa, con tales resultados y no sé por qué falla*. El problema, tal y como está planteada la pregunta ahora mismo es que tendríamos que ponernos a intentar adivinar el problema, luego de haber comprendido todo tu código, sin tener delante de nosotros un escenario de prueba real. Así es harto complicado poder ayudarte. Sin duda es un problema simple, pero plantear una pregunta sin depurar antes hace todo cuesta arriba.

Comment: Casi todo los entornos de desarrollo te permiten poner puntos de interrupción en el código, o sea, en esos puntos el código se detiene y puedes analizar el contenido de cada variable en ese punto. Si no es el caso, entoces existe `var_dump`  el cual puedes usar para probar las variables allí donde falla. Si no haces eso, tendríamos que hacerlo nosotros por ti, y eso es imposible, porque no tenemos a mano todo tu contexto: código completo, base de datos, sistema de archivos, etc. Aprender a depurar es fundamental, te ahorrará mucho tiempo desarrollando tus programas.